Cycle in dependencies between targets 'WatchApp' and 'App'; building could produce unreliable results
I'm trying to create a watch app for my current iOS app, but even though I'm not importing any frameworks or dependencies in my watch target, it gives me this error:
Cycle in dependencies between targets 'Insightfull' and 'Insightfull WatchKit Watch App'; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle path: Insightfull → Insightfull WatchKit Watch App → Insightfull
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Insightfull' has copy command from '/Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/Insightfull WatchKit Watch App.app' to '/Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Insightfull.app/Watch/Insightfull WatchKit Watch App.app'
→ Target 'Insightfull WatchKit Watch App': CodeSign /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/Insightfull WatchKit Watch App.app
○ Target 'Insightfull WatchKit Watch App': CodeSign /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/Insightfull WatchKit Watch App.app
→ Target 'Insightfull' has process command with output '/Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Insightfull.app/Info.plist'


Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node: <all> ->

command: <all> ->

node: /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Insightfull.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Insightfull.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ExtractedAppShortcutsMetadata.stringsdata ->

command: P0:target-Insightfull-d9c2816c65a02dfabbbe7a71547e5f047f09f7f4df4f256fc32431abdfd4c27a-:Debug:ExtractAppIntentsMetadata ->

node: <target-Insightfull-d9c2816c65a02dfabbbe7a71547e5f047f09f7f4df4f256fc32431abdfd4c27a--fused-phase2-copy-files> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Insightfull-d9c2816c65a02dfabbbe7a71547e5f047f09f7f4df4f256fc32431abdfd4c27a--fused-phase2-copy-files ->

node: <target-Insightfull-d9c2816c65a02dfabbbe7a71547e5f047f09f7f4df4f256fc32431abdfd4c27a--fused-phase1-copy-files> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Insightfull-d9c2816c65a02dfabbbe7a71547e5f047f09f7f4df4f256fc32431abdfd4c27a--fused-phase1-copy-files ->

node: <Copy /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Insightfull.app/Watch/Insightfull WatchKit Watch App.app> ->

CYCLE POINT ->

command: P0:target-Insightfull-d9c2816c65a02dfabbbe7a71547e5f047f09f7f4df4f256fc32431abdfd4c27a-:Debug:Copy /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Insightfull.app/Watch/Insightfull WatchKit Watch App.app /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/Insightfull WatchKit Watch App.app ->

node: /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/Insightfull WatchKit Watch App.app/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: � ->

node: /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/Insightfull WatchKit Watch App.app/_CodeSignature ->

command: P0:target-Insightfull WatchKit Watch App-d9c2816c65a02dfabbbe7a71547e5f048c10c4a4d72020b16b4193f3d32cfebb-:Debug:CodeSign /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/Insightfull WatchKit Watch App.app ->

node: /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Insightfull.app/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: � ->

node: /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Insightfull.app/Info.plist ->

command: P0:target-Insightfull-d9c2816c65a02dfabbbe7a71547e5f047f09f7f4df4f256fc32431abdfd4c27a-:Debug:ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Insightfull.app/Info.plist /Users/rohanrocks/Xcode/Insightfull/Insightfull/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Insightfull.app/Watch/Insightfull WatchKit Watch App.app ->

command: P0:target-Insightfull-d9c2816c65a02dfabbbe7a71547e5f047f09f7f4df4f256fc32431abdfd4c27a-:Debug:Copy /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Insightfull.app/Watch/Insightfull WatchKit Watch App.app /Users/rohanrocks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Insightfull-fdmnpootxbwpoaeqfjfhyzrrrstx/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/Insightfull WatchKit Watch App.app

Let me know if there's any other information I need to provide
Xcode Version 16.1 (16B40)
macOS Sequoia 15.2 Beta 1
M3 Macbook Pro (November 2023)
